# Using an External C++ DLL in C# WPF application

Tags: c#, c++, wpf, dll

Full disclosure... I'm a C/C++/C# newb.
I have been playing around with ssdeep on my linux box (http://ssdeep.sourceforge.net/).

The Python wrapper works great (https://python-ssdeep.readthedocs.org/en/latest/usage.html). I am now trying to write a Windows GUI application (C# WPF) that uses this library. In the Windows Binary download, there are a number of files, including a DLL and a DEF file.

In the API.TXT file, the author writes:

> The Windows ssdeep package includes a Win32 DLL and a .def file.
>   Although MSVC users can't use the DLL directly, they can easily create
>   a .lib file using the Microsoft LIB tool:
>
> C:> lib /machine:i386 /def:fuzzy.def
>
> You can then compile your program using the resulting library:
>
> C:> cl sample.c fuzzy.lib

I have done this, and I now have `fuzzy.dll`, `fuzzy.def`, `fuzzy.exp`, and `fuzzy.lib`. After much googling, I am unsure how to actually use these files in my WPF application.

Where do I put it (whatever file I need) in my solution? Do I need to use `using System.Runtime.InteropServices;`? Preferably, I'd be packaging this dll or lib in my code so its not an external dependency, but at this point, I'd just be happy to call a function in the library.

Edit:

I found [this old link](http://jessekornblum.livejournal.com/249104.html?view=704016#t704016) which gave me this code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;


namespace FuzzyBear
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {


        [DllImport("fuzzy.dll")]
        public static extern int fuzzy_hash_filename([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] string fname, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] string result);


        [DllImport("fuzzy.dll")]
        public static extern int fuzzy_compare(string sig1, string sig2);


public MainWindow()
        {
            string result = "";
            int test = fuzzy_hash_filename("C:\\dev\\tools\\ssdeep-2.13\\API.txt", result);
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write("Lookie here: ");
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(test.ToString());
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

Which gives me this error:

```
Additional information: A call to PInvoke function 'FuzzyBear!FuzzyBear.MainWindow::fuzzy_hash_filename' has unbalanced the stack. This is likely because the managed PInvoke signature does not match the unmanaged target signature. Check that the calling convention and parameters of the PInvoke signature match the target unmanaged signature.
```

What does it mean when the signature doesn't match? Does it mean that my function's input doesn't match the [header file's](http://ssdeep.sourceforge.net/api/html/fuzzy_8h.html) input? These are the functions from the cpp header file:

```
int     fuzzy_hash_filename (const char *filename, char *result)
int     fuzzy_compare (const char *sig1, const char *sig2)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't link to static libraries in C# like you can with C++, so you can't package the code together.  In order to use your library you will need a Win32 DLL - if you only have a .lib you will need to create a wrapper DLL for it.

If you do have a valid Win32 DLL you can use P/Invoke to call methods on the C++ DLL from C#.

To do this you need to declare each C++ method you want to use using DllImport.  I can't help you with the exact syntax as it will depend on the methods you want to use from your DLL.  An example of this is:

DllImport("gdi32.dll", ExactSpelling=true, SetLastError=true)]
static extern IntPtr SelectObject(IntPtr hdc, IntPtr hgdiobj);

There is a library of DllImport declarations for standard Win32 DLLs at [http://www.pinvoke.net] which should help get you started.

Once declared you can call methods as you would in .Net.  The gotcha is how you deal with marshalling the different data types - you will need to understand how to use IntPtr.

Answer (score 1):

You have a DLL. You need to use PInvoke to call the methods in the it.

I strongly suggest you get Adam Nathans excellent book that covers pinvoke in detail [http://www.amazon.com/NET-COM-Complete-Interoperability-Guide/dp/067232170X](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/067232170X)

Pinvoke in tutorials is simple, in real life it can get complicated. It depends on the method signatures

Comment: Thanks, I'll check that book out.